# Repeat values in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Imagine a matrix :

```
a =

     4
     2
     8
     9
```

I need to repeat it *n* times. If `n = 3`, the result is :

```
a =

     4
     4
     4
     2
     2
     2
     8
     8
     8
     9
     9
     9
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try:

```
n = 3; 
reshape(repmat(a', n, 1), numel(a)*n, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the kron function, 
newMatrix = kron(a,ones(1,4))